# How to get user home folder in Vala?

Tags: vala, home

I am trying to make a Elementary OS app that I need to get user home folder. I tried `GLib.Environment.get_home_dir ()` and `Granite.Services.Paths.home_folder.get_path ()` but they both return `null`. What is the proper way to get user's home folder for Elementary OS?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    xdg_path = new Granite.Services.Paths();
    app_xdg_path.initialize (Constants.bookworm_id, Constants.INSTALL_SCRIPTS_DIR);
    bookworm_config_path = app_xdg_path.user_data_folder.get_path();
```

Are you missing the initialize step

Answer (score 0):

`Granite.Services.Paths` is now deprecated and uses `GLib.Environment.get_home_dir ()` internally anyway.

If `GLib.Environment.get_home_dir ()` is returning `null`, I believe there is probably something wrong with your setup/install as this method works on my system.

I believe it uses the `HOME` environment variable, so check this is set and isn't being overwritten by something else.